# How to fix no outer ring when creating a project in Django (vscode)?

Tags: python-3.x, django, visual-studio-code

I have this problem when creating a project in Django that only a package `\<nameoftheproject\>`  gets created and not the outer container (with the same name as the package) that was supposed to be created with the code below. Is this a bug that is not there or doesn't appear in the project dir in VSCode anymore(the course I am doing is from 2018, so maybe it doesn't appear)? I could go without it and build an easy application, but I couldn't deploy it using Git and Heroku.  This is a source code I used in the terminal to start a project:

1. `mkdir vidly`
2. `cd vidly`
3. `pipenv install django==2.1`
4. `django-admin startproject \<nameoftheproject .`
5. `code .`

Note: I tried creating a project in the global environment (instead of `pipenv`). Didn't work. Using a different Django version didn't work either.

Comment: `django-admin startproject <nameoftheproject .` you have a dot at the end of this command right? Then this is expected behaviour, it will use the current directory as the project directory, what is the problem with this?

Comment: Well my online course teacher says there should be an outer cointainer in the project folder that is not a main folder and not a package. He said it stores all the data. The problem I get is that I cannot deploy my application. When I write: <git push heroku master> or modifications with branches <branchname>:main  it either says the repository is empty or that it is duplicated. I am also thinking that the problem is I didn't do it with pipenv but with pip instead. Just trying to figure out how to make this work. Thanks.

Comment: When you don't add `.` at the end of the command Django does create 2 nested directories with the project name, if you add the dot it simply means to skip the project directory and use the current one as it. Your error doesn't have anything to do with that, you have some other misconfiguration. Are you sure you have even initialized a git repository?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot for helping out. Very useful information. I solved this problem, there was a mistake I've made in Procfile's code. Now it works :). Thanks again!